# Get friend id using Facebook api to tag uploaded photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have the following code

```
$taggable = (new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'GET',
'/me/friends'
))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $taggable, 1) . '</pre>';
```

I am trying to get the id of the list of friends who is also using the app, so that the user can tag the photo with these friends. Right now the code prints the friends who are also using the app, their name and id. I want to get the id of a friend to sub into the parameters of "tags", however the getProperty('id') doesn't work and gives me an error. I am new to facebook api so I am unfamiliar with the syntax.

How do I get the id of the friend to sub into:

```
 'tags' => '[{\'tag_uid\': \'testing\'}]',
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've made the API call, you'll get a list of friends like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "aaa", 
      "id": "111"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "bbb", 
      "id": "222"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "ccc", 
      "id": "333"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Assuming you want to tag the first person, you can get the ID as so:

```
$id = $taggable['data'][0]->id;
```

This will set `$id` as `111`.

You can then call the API to tag the Photo, as follows:

```
// set tags object (user_id, and position)
$tags = array( array( 'tag_uid' => $id, 'x' => 0, 'y' => 0 ) );

// call api, with json_encoded $tags
$tag = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/{photo_id}/tags', array( 'tags' => json_encode( $tags ) ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// output result
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $tag, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: I am having some problems. I saved the id's that I want to tag in an array $id. Then I used implode to create a string and stored it in $friend_id. I then used $friend_id instead of $id in the tag parameter... however, it returns a different number :S. When I print the string, it returns the ids correctly but then changes when I used it in the tag. Do you know why?

Comment: @fondillusions , the structure returned by graph is a mix of one or more arrays, and objects.

Comment: And now my complete comment...

@fondillusions , the structure returned by graph is a mix of one or more arrays, and objects.
Have a look at the print_r at the top of Niraj's post: the "data" block is an array (marked with [ ]'s), within that are objects, each containing a name and an id field.
The simplest route to use it like you tried would be to walk through the array, extract the name and id values (using the ->name and ->id of the array-elements) and stuffing those into a more simple array.
From there you can do things like implode.